# How to integrate citruspay payment gateway in yii2

Tags: yii2

How to integrate citruspay payment gateway in yii2? Citruspay provide library for payment integration. When i am using that library it gives error "Class 'seller\citruspay\lib\Zend_Config_Ini' not found" - any in this will be appreciated

```html
 PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
Class 'seller\modules\citruspay\controllers\CitrusPay' not found

    1. in C:\wamp\www\haggl\seller\modules\citruspay\controllers\DefaultController.php at line 44
    35363738394041424344454647484950515253

                    "cardHolderName" => Yii::$app->request->post('cardHolderName'),
                    "cardNumber" => Yii::$app->request->post('cardNumber'),
                    "expiryMonth" => Yii::$app->request->post('expiryMonth'),
                    "cardType" => Yii::$app->request->post('cardType'),
                    "cvvNumber" => Yii::$app->request->post('cvvNumber'),
                    "expiryYear" => Yii::$app->request->post('expiryYear'),
                    "returnUrl" => Yii::$app->request->post('returnUrl'),
                    "amount" => Yii::$app->request->post('amount'),
                );
                CitrusPay::setApiKey("apikey",'sandbox');
                $response = Transaction::create($tarr,CitrusPay::getApiKey());
                $redirectUrl = $response->get_redirect_url();
                $response_code = $response->get_resp_code();
                if($redirectUrl != "" && $response_code == 200)
                {
                    return $this->redirect($redirectUrl);
                }else{
                    $html = "<p>Response Code is ".$response->get_resp_code()."</p>";
                    $html .= "<p>Response Message is ".$response->get_resp_msg()."</p>";

    2. in C:\wamp\www\haggl\seller\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php – call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\haggl\seller\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php:55}() at line 55
    3. in C:\wamp\www\haggl\seller\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php – yii\base\InlineAction::runWithParams() at line 151
    4. in C:\wamp\www\haggl\seller\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php – yii\base\Controller::runAction() at line 455
    5. in C:\wamp\www\haggl\seller\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php – yii\base\Module::runAction() at line 83
    6. in C:\wamp\www\haggl\seller\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php – yii\web\Application::handleRequest() at line 375
    7. in C:\wamp\www\haggl\seller\index.php – yii\base\Application::run() at line 22
    16171819202122

        require(__DIR__ . '/../common/config/main-local.php'),
        require(__DIR__ . '/config/main.php'),
        require(__DIR__ . '/config/main-local.php')
    );
     
    $application = new yii\web\Application($config);
    $application->run();
```

Comment: i think you'll have to provide some more information. Show some code where the class is initiated, and maybe the folder structure where your code initiates the library, and where the library is stored.

Comment: i have installed the library in index.php

Comment: defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

set_include_path(__DIR__ . '/citruspay/lib'.PATH_SEPARATOR.get_include_path());
require_once(__DIR__ . '/citruspay/lib/CitrusPay.php');

require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../common/config/aliases.php');

Comment: it give error when i am calling the api in my controller

Comment: have a look here. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-yii-integration.html

Comment: I have seen and followed this too, but no help...

Comment: I am getting error when i am calling the Api Classes - It give error like:- " PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
Class 'seller\citruspay\lib\Zend_Config_Ini' not found"

Comment: I think you need to update your question. Show us where in the directory structure you have your library installed, show us what you have tried, and what errors are generated with the different approaches.

Comment: Thanks Jorgen, for your effort. Finally i am able to integrate the library in Yii2 Framework

Comment: Thats great. Could you answer your own question so that it might help other users having the same problem?

Comment: Yes why not... I am editing my Question

Comment: Better yet, add it as a answer and accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

In "index.php" file which is present in Yii2 folder make changes as given below,

```html
<?php
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

// register CitrusPay path to yii enviornment
set_include_path(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/components/CitrusPay/lib'.PATH_SEPARATOR.get_include_path());

// register CitrusPay autoloader
require(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/components/CitrusPay/lib/CitrusPay.php');

// register Composer autoloader
require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');

// include Yii class file
require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

Yii::$classMap['CitrusPay'] = (realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/components/CitrusPay/lib/CitrusPay.php');

// load application aliases
require(__DIR__ . '/../common/config/aliases.php');

// load application configuration
$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../common/config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../common/config/main-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/config/main-local.php')
);

$application = new yii\web\Application($config);
$application->run();
```

And then call the library classes using the "use" keyword

For Example: 
use CitrusPay;

And it will work like a charm..